# Trying to implement a type of qstion into a django quiz

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to implement an already existing type of question into an already existing quiz. 
So I'm using this quiz app:
https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz
I am trying to implement this:
https://github.com/rodrigosetti/recruitr
which is a coding challange into the quiz above. 
Does anyone have an idea on how I would do that. It is not as simple as copying models from one place to the other.
A detailed answer would be perfect but even a rough idea will be very appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: also if you are only interested in creating an online form you could try : https://www.google.com/forms/about/ or some similar service.